# Any way to merge list of txt files (with splitted lines) into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of `txt` files for fake news text and I want to put them in pandas dataframe. However, in single text file, the first row and third row were separated, that is same for all csv files. However, I want them in pandas dataframe for simple data manipulation. I tried following on my data:

```
cols, vals = zip(*[line.split('\n') for line in StringIO("biz01.fake.txt").read().split('\n\n')])
s = pd.Series(vals, cols)
s.index = [s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), s.index]
s.unstack()
```

but I got an error which I couldn't understand why.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Can anyone help me how to make this happen? Any solution to get this done?

Here is my original data looks like:

[input txt files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Scz.png)

and here is how list of txt files (on my local drive) looks like:
[list of txt files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osrhq.png)

**example desired output**

```
1   first_row     second_row
2   headers_1     some text
3   headers_2     some texts
```

I put some example text files on the [flies](https://jmp.sh/9KIB5Uu). Can anyone help me how to get this done? Any idea?

**New update**:

when I tried the following solution, I get this type of output:

[new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIu9w.png)

in my input txt file, the second row is a very long text, I just want two column dataframe with default column names. any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to read in your files and then drop the empty rows.

For example, here's a text file, "news.txt"

```
Alex Jones Vindicated in "Pizzagate" Controversy

"Alex Jones, purveyor of the independent investigative news website Infowars and host of The Alex Jones Show, has been vindicated in his claims regarding the so-called "Pizzagate" controversy. Jones and others uncovered evidence last year that top Democratic Party officials were involved in a bizarre, satanic child sex cult and pornography ring using the Washington D.C. pizza parlor Comet Ping Pong Pizza as a front. The allegations rocked the Democratic Party and may have caused serious damage to the Hillary Clinton presidential campaign. Top U.S. federal investigators have now confirmed that they have verified many of these claims after executing raids on the offices of several of the key players. Charges are expected to be filed in the coming days. The news comes as a welcome vindication for Jones, who has been accused by many mainstream media outlets of being a conspiracy theorist and of publishing "fake news". Mr. Jones has often drawn controversy, and was scapegoated in media reports as an example of how inaccurate and misleading news proliferated on social media websites like Facebook, Youtube and Twitter during the 2016 election. Jones has also exposed inconsistencies in the official government accounts of the 9/11 terrorist attacks and the Sandy Hook school shooting in Newtown Connecticut."
```

Then I use the code

```
df = pd.read_csv('news.txt', header = None, sep = '\n', skip_blank_lines = True)
#df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all', inplace = True)
df = df.T
df.columns = ['Header', 'Rows']
```

which outputs

```
                                              Header    Rows
0   Alex Jones Vindicated in "Pizzagate" Controversy    Alex Jones, purveyor of the independent invest...
```

Comment: Is that possible to make output well formatted? Do you mind to try the files on the fly: [link](https://jmp.sh/9KIB5Uu) because when I tried your solution it didn't produce what I want. Thanks

Comment: I updated my post with your solution, could you try again? because if I tried your solution it didn't produce right output.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Your files are different from what I thought. Can you post a better idea of what your expected output is?

Comment: my expected output is pretty simple, I just put my input data in pandas dataframe with two columns such as `header` and `text`. Do you have a better idea? please see my updated post. Thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity I edited my answer. Try that and let me know how it works.

Comment: still not working on my input data, when I tried to assign column name like `df.columns=["header", "text"]` it raised value error; Would you mind to try out file on the flies? Thanks

Comment: Forgot to include `header=None`, and adding sep = '\n' told `pandas` how to parse the file.

Comment: yeah, it works pretty good now. what if I try this solution for list of txt files where list of files in another folder? Could you point me out how to do it?

Comment: Just get the list of files the same way you're doing now, but change the path to the new folder so that it's reading the files from that folder.